# what is the difference between while(n--) and while(n=n-1)?

Tags: c++, c

What is the difference between `while(n--)` and `while(n=n-1)`? When I use `while(n=n-1)` in my code, I can input less than 1 number.

Example: First input 3 than input 3 times a single number (but not happening this in `while(n=n-1)`).
But when I use `while(n--)`, it's normal.

My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    long long inum;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n--)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &inum);
        if(inum == 0 || inum % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("even\n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf("odd\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `while(--n)` to the mix...

Comment: its also giving me same result as like while(n=n-1) < I input 3 and than i can input 2 times numbers ! :(

Comment: Well now you can search for the difference between `n--` and `--n`, which is described all over the place.

Comment: To see in practice what is the difference, you can compile and see what your compiler is doing.
In gcc:
`gcc -S my_source.c -o my_source.s`
It will make the compiler stop in assembly step, then you can compare both source codes and see what is the difference in terms of assembly.

Comment: Thanks all . its worked .. hahaha...forgot to replied .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `n--` is the previous value of `n`

```
int n = 10;
// value of (n--) is 10
// you can assign that value to another variable and print it
int k = (n--);                     // extra parenthesis for clarity
printf("value of n-- is %d\n", k);
```

The value of `n = n - 1` is 1 less than the previous value of `n`

```
int n = 10;
// value of (n = n - 1) is 9
// you can assign that value to another variable and print it
int k = (n = n - 1);                     // extra parenthesis for clarity
printf("value of n = n - 1 is %d\n", k);
```

Answer (score 1):

`while(n--)` uses `n` in its body, and the decremented value is used for the next iteration.

`while(n=n-1)` is the same as `while(--n)`, which decrements and uses this new value of `n` in its body.

Comment: The value of `n` changes while evaluating the condition in the `while` condition. The value seen by the while condition is the value before any change. Immediately after the condition is tested (at the next sequence point) the valued stored in `n` has been changed. I mean: your first paragraph is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks all . its worked .. hahaha...forgot to replied .